# WPF Magic Strings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So the more I work with WPF and third party vendors like Infragistics, it seems there is one common practice that confuses me.

Why do template parts have "magic strings"?

[image]

Everything I have been taught since inception into this field is MVVM, decouple, no magic strings and numbers, no one knows about anyone else, ect...

So if that's the case isn't there a better way to do this? Why do we accept this as common practice?

Comment: IMO this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276446/naming-of-wpf-controls-in-markup as that question is asking why the names are "PART_" and not "m_" whereas this question is asking why template parts are strings and not something else.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland I have to agree with you that the marked duplicate doesn't pertain to my question. However, now that it's been closed, it is dead...  :-(  There's no recovering from this...

Comment: Another case where string references come up are in named references in bindings/triggers.  Really, though, these shouldn't be thought of as raw strings, but rather as identifier names, just like names of classes or names of properties.  The main difference is the reduced availability of static analysis to make sure that your named identifiers are referenced appropriately, enabling runtime failures for things like typos.  Ultimately, though, it's the same concept.

Comment: @DanBryant I'll buy that.

Comment: @DanBryant I've added to my answer - you can make the magic strings constants and use them as such, reducing typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templating is all about changing the visual parts of a control. Naming is a way of labeling those parts so they can be referenced elsewhere.

MVVM is about binding data to a control, but templating is a view only concern, hence why templating doesn't know about MVVM.

When you're changing a template you shouldn't need to know anything about the data the control will be bound to. If a controls template is data specific that's an anti-pattern in my opinion.

DataTemplates are where you want to use data related templating. Then in the control template you'd use a presenter like a ContentPresenter or ItemsPresenter to give the control template somewhere to display the data.

---

Side note - Often these things are just set as strings but can be defined as constants, thus you can refactor them, etc.

```
public class MyParts {
    public static const string MyFoo = "PART_Foo";
}

[TemplatePart(Name = MyParts.MyFoo)]

<Button x:Name="{x:Static parts:MyParts.MyFoo}" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

All the links I can find to the original WPF "Best Practices Guidelines" seem to be dead these days, but as far as I can recall, it's been the convention from the XAML team.  Because of the nature of XAML controls, that you can customise them in various way, the "PART_" prefix warned you that there was some code which was going to directly look for that element and do something with it.  So effectively you didn't want to remove it or change the name or the base functionality of the control would cease to behave as expected, but you could add other elements around it to customise how it worked.